# Why the Born-Infeld-like non-linear electrodynamics are considered to be the functions of ${\cal F} + c\,{{\cal G}^2}$?

Tags: electromagnetism, field-theory

The born-Infeld Lagrangian is written as

${{\cal L}_{BI}} = {b^2}\left( {1 - \sqrt {1 - \frac{{2{\cal F}}}{{{b^2}}} - \frac{{{{\cal G}^2}}}{{{b^4}}}} } \right)$

and the Born-Infeld-like non-linear electrodynamics such as logarithmic and exponential electrodynamics are given by

${{\cal L}_{Lg}} =  - {b^2}\ln \left( {1 - \frac{X}{{{b^2}}}} \right)$,

and

${{\cal L}_{Ex}} = {b^2}\left( {{e^{ - X/{b^2} - 1}}} \right)$,

where
$X = {\cal F} + \frac{{{{\cal G}^2}}}{{2{b^2}}}$.

My question is why these Lagrangians are considered to be functions of ${\cal F} + \frac{{{{\cal G}^2}}}{{2{b^2}}}$ and not other combinations of ${\cal F}$ and ${\cal G}$ ?
I know that odd powers of ${\cal G}$ are ignored due to parity considerations but still there may be many other combinations.

note: ${\cal F}$ and ${\cal G}$ are Maxwell invariants:

${\cal F} = \frac{1}{4}{F_{\mu \nu }}{F^{\mu \nu }}$,

${\cal G} = \frac{1}{4}{F_{\mu \nu }}{{\tilde F}^{\mu \nu }}$
with
${{\tilde F}^{\mu \nu }} = \frac{1}{2}{\varepsilon ^{\mu \nu \alpha \beta }}{F_{\alpha \beta }}$.

Comment: I haven't seen this model before. What kind of object are $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$?

Comment: @catalogue_number Sorry not to mention that. I edited the question and introduced ${\cal F}$ and ${\cal G}$.

Comment: And further - what exactly do you mean by "a function of F + G^2/2b^2"? The Lagrangian density is still a function $\mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}$, evaluated on the four $A$ potentials.

Comment: Sure. The Lagrangians are based on the four $A$ potential. But as it is seen in the Born-Infeld, Logarithmic and Exponential Lagrangians they are functions of  ${\cal F} + c\,{{\cal G}^2}$. Shouldn't we say that?

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're asking. You're right - in principle, the Lagrangian could be any real function of any combination of $\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G}$, but in general would not lead to anything resembling Maxwell electromagnetism.